# Domain is issuing trust certificate instead of root authority

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, certificate

I was running into an issue on Windows Server 2012 R2 where any website I visited was throwing a untrusted certificate error. I circumvented this issue by copying the certifications from another machine on the network that did not have this problem (was Windows 7 machine), for all the missing Third Party and Root certifications.

I exported them via running certmgr.msc and exporting from the source machine into my 2012 R2 server machine. Now I am having a unique problem where the local server on the domain is issuing all the certifications instead of say Verisign. Picture below from source machine vs server.

[Source Machine Certification Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf0wq.png)

[Server Machine Certification path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd1gE.png)

Internet Explorer works but using Firefox will still throw an error when vising any website (e.g. www.google.com). I verified in my source machine that the local machine is in the Trusted Root authority certifications (as it also is in my Server 2012 R2 machine).

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Your 'server' machine is apparently having its traffic intercepted. If this is authorized, perhaps on a business or school network, confirm with the admin what cert(s) you should expect and accept. If this is not authorized, you have probably been hacked and all your data stolen. Firefox does not use the Windows certificate store but its own separate one, so it still detects the interception. If you want to accept a CA cert in Firefox, import it *into Firefox*.

Comment: @dave_thomson_085 Server is on a business network. But a different computer on the same network has the exact same certificates and it is using the correct certification path (as noted in the picture). My server machine is on the same network with the exact certificate as other machine but is using its own domain to issue certificates. Any other things I can try? The issue is with me being able to use some programs as my server refuses to authenticate with the program's webservers

Comment: Your evidence doesn't show 'the server' is issuing these certs, only *something* in your local net. If you want to find/identify it: check if you have a proxy defined for HTTP and/or HTTPS, and if so where it is and what it does. Check if you have any layer in your TCP/IP stack with a description like 'network security', 'data/endpoint protection', 'safe browsing', or similar. Check with Wireshark if you're actually getting the modified certs from an outside address, an internal address, an outside IP using a 'transparent' internal MAC, or not from any other machine at all. ...

Comment: ... If you have a program that should use the Windows truststore and doesn't, identify the program or at least its SSL/TLS-related part. One common case is Java: Java doesn't use the Windows truststore, but instead has at least one of its own and often several.